# Laravel 3 blade template is not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm learning Laravel 3, but Blade template is not working. My code seems correct, but all it displays is `@layout('master')`. Pages source also contains this text only.
`application\views\home\index.blade.php` contents:

```
@layout('master')

@section('main')
    {{ $greeting }}
@endsection
```

`application\views\master.blade.php` contents:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello world!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        @yield('main')
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and in `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('/, home', function()
{
$greeting = "Hello world";
return View::make('home.index')->with('greeting',$greeting);
});
```

What can cause blade not to work? I tried Laravel 4 also, and changed `@layout` to `@extends`, `@endsection` to `@stop` but same situation. I get only `@extends('master')`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure...but I think its because you have a space at the top of your file....

```
@layout('master')
```

needs to be directly at the top of the file for it to work properly...
Else it just echoes @layout('master') as words to the page, if you know what Im trying to say :)

Answer (score 0):

same on me in L4...
check your charset of your code editor! sometimes some hidden chars are at the beginning of the file.
i switched to "UTF-8 without BOM"

Comment: in L4 reinstalling solved the issue. But don't know what's the problem with L3.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove every space or EOL, CR, LF, Enter, \n (or whatever) before your code.
Same issue in Laravel 4, I followed the [quick start](http://laravel.com/docs/quick#creating-a-view) the step where you create a view I leave a new line.

```
-New line here, and it brokes-
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
    Users!
@stop
```

Again remove anything before `@extends('layout')` and it works for me!!