# blade template loading in public directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am totally new to laravel and just started a fresh app with it. I am trying to do a simple hello world project and wen i create a template with .blade.php extention i get the folowing error

```
[Tue Jan 14 14:22:50 2014] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/ramza/apps/php/testsite/bootstrap/../public/index.blade.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/ramza/apps/php/testsite/server.php on line 19
```

my controller code is below

```
class GamesController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
            // Show a listing of games.
            return View::make('games.index');
    }
}
```

my index.blade.php file is empty with just hello world in it ans it looks like it is trying to load it in the public directory.

I tried to put this file in the public directory and it worked perfectly fine

but inside app/views/games/index.blade.php the error occurs. any help. thanks.

**Update**

app/config/view.php

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | View Storage Paths
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Most templating systems load templates from disk. Here you may specify
    | an array of paths that should be checked for your views. Of course
    | the usual Laravel view path has already been registered for you.
    |
    */

    'paths' => array(__DIR__.'/../views'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Pagination View
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This view will be used to render the pagination link output, and can
    | be easily customized here to show any view you like. A clean view
    | compatible with Twitter's Bootstrap is given to you by default.
    |
    */

    'pagination' => 'pagination::slider-3',

);
```

my route file

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'GamesController@index');
```

Comment: That is weird indeed. Could you please share the contents of `app/config/view.php`? That file shows exactly what folders the View engine should look in to find templates.

Comment: updated it. i wonder what i am doing wrong

Comment: its in my games folder in the views folder and its empty

Comment: What url are you using? /public/games ?

Comment: @MrShibby update my route file

Comment: I mean, what URL in your browser are you using to access the page?

Comment: @MrShibby the url i am using is http://localhost:8000/

Comment: Have you tried to add /testsite or /testsite/public to your current URL (after localhost:8000)? But it's weird I don't know what could be the reason of that.

Comment: if i remove the index.blade.php and rename it to index.php it works fine

Comment: @MrShibby the public url trows the following error `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException`

Comment: finally fixed the issue. my text editor was not creating the file properly. created the file manually ant it worked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996413/laravel-3-blade-template-is-not-working

Comment: Ok, you mean not at the right place? Anyway, good for you!

Comment: afere a long test. i am back to the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your webserver is pointing to the /public dir as the webroot?

Comment: i think the issue is from the character encoding. Switched to utf-8 and it works perfectly.